How to change height of navigation bar and items size?
I want to create navigation controller and navigation bar programatically. I want to change height and items size and position. My navigation bar height = 74 and item size = 50x50. Also item top space = 12 and bottom = 12. I trying to do it with this code:
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    if let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        let navigationController = UINavigationController()
        let viewController = ViewController()
        navigationController.viewControllers = [viewController]
        window.rootViewController = navigationController
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}

ViewController
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .gray
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height = 74
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        
        let menuBtn = UIButton(type: .custom)
        menuBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 12.0, width: 50, height: 50)
        menuBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"mute"), for: .normal)

        let menuBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: menuBtn)
        menuBarItem.customView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        menuBarItem.customView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        menuBarItem.setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment(12.0, for: .default)
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = menuBarItem
    }

But it doesn't work. I don't see the height of the navigation bar changed, nor the size and position of the navigation buttons. How to solve a problem?

Had you set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false for menuBarItem ?

@Elevo Value of type 'UIBarButtonItem' has no member 'translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints'

oh my fault, I meant it's customView 

There is no way to increase navigation bar height. But instead, we can use private API, called "_UINavigationBarPalette", used in Apple apps, such as Calendar and Fitness.
let contentView = UIView()
contentView.frame.size.height = 100.0

let _UINavigationBarPalette = NSClassFromString(["_", "UI", "Navigation", "Bar", "Palette"].joined()) as! UIView.Type
let palette = _UINavigationBarPalette.perform(NSSelectorFromString("alloc"))
    .takeUnretainedValue()
    .perform(NSSelectorFromString("initWithContentView:"), with: contentView)
    .takeUnretainedValue()
        
navigationItem.perform(NSSelectorFromString(["_", "set", "Bottom", "Palette", ":"].joined()), with: palette)

Please note, that I split raw strings to bypass AppStore static analyser. Otherwise your app will be rejected due to private API usage.
Source: https://x.com/search?q=_UINavigationBarPalette&src=typed_query

Why we can't use custom toolbar in app like Calendar and Fitness?  I'm not sure this great. I don't want to use private API. And this method does not help in any way to increase the size of items

@user1342352532 They don't use custom toolbar, only _UINavigationBarPalette. This is truly native way to increase navigation bar height.

Ok. But what about item size and position? I want to change it

@user1342352532 try to add your view as navigationBar subview, using navigationBar.addSubview, instead of setting it as item.

Ok. But I want to change back button size. What I need to do this?

@user1342352532 custom back button

Try this instead.
You can just wrap your viewController in a UINavigationController when you're setting the rootViewController.
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    if let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
               self.window.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController())
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}


In this case I can't see navigation vc

To customize navigation bar, I make custom view and use for top bar.
So code goes as below.
TopBar.swift
class TopBar: UIView {
    var backButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    var accountButtom = UIButton(type: .custom)
    var statusBarView : UIView = UIView()
    var titleLabel = UILabel()
    var logoImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "top_bar_logo.png"))
    var delegate : TopBarDelegate?
    
    @objc func backButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.backPressed()
    }
    
    @objc func accountButtomClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.accountPressed()
    }

    func setupView() {
        
        self.backgroundColor = AppColors.topBarBackgroundColor
        
        // handle UI UI here
        for each in [backButton, accountButtom, titleLabel, statusBarView]{
            self.addSubview(each)
            each.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        backButton.Top == self.Top + (safeAreaTopHeight + 12)
        // 7 because your top bar height is 74 and button height is 50 so (74-50) = 24 and to bring button in center we will leave 12 from top (25/12)
        backButton.Width == 50
        backButton.Height == 50
        
        self.Height == topBarInnerHeight + safeAreaTopHeight
        
    }
    
}
    
protocol TopBarDelegate {
    func backPressed()
    func accountPressed()
}

BaseVC.swift
import UIKit
import Stevia

class BaseVC: UIViewController {

    var topBar = TopBar()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.addSubview(topBar)
        setupView()
    }
    
    func setupView() {
        for each in [topBar] {
            each.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        adjustTopBar()
    }
    
    func adjustTopBar() {
        // handle UI
        topBar.Top == self.view.Top
        topBar.fillHorizontally()
        // here topBarInnerHeight = your height which is 74
        topBar.Height == topBarInnerHeight + safeAreaTopHeight
        topBar.setupView()
        topBar.delegate = self
        
        print("screenWidth==\(screenWidth)")
    }
    
}

extension BaseVC : TopBarDelegate {
    
    func backPressed() {
        print("backPressed")
        takeMeBack()
    }
    
    func accountPressed() {
        print("accountPressed")
    }
    
}

safeAreaTopHeight you will calculate in first view controller (for me its SplashVC.swift)
var safeAreaTopHeight : CGFloat = 0

class SplashVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
                safeAreaTopHeight = window.safeAreaInsets.top
            }
            
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                if let window2 = UIApplication.shared.windows.first {
                    safeAreaTopHeight = window2.safeAreaInsets.top
                }
            }
            print("innn---005")
        }
    }
}

And create this variable in Constants file.
Now whenever you create any view controller extend it by base as below.
class YourViewController : BaseVC {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}


What about translucent background, when there is content under top bar?

@Dewerro : At that time, hide topbar... topBar.isHidden = true
